# How to access completion of session.activateSession() in Watch OS2?

Tags: swift, apple-watch, watchos-2

When my Watch app loads, I don't think my `getDataFromPhone` and `loadTableData` methods are getting called (below),  however the forceTouch method get's them to load fine.  So I think my session isn't activating in time to call `getDataFromPhone` and `loadTableData`.  How can I implement a completion block on `activateSession` so those methods aren't called until then?

```
override func willActivate() {
        // This method is called when watch view controller is about to be visible to user
        super.willActivate()

        if (WCSession.isSupported()) {
            session = WCSession.defaultSession()
            session.delegate = self
            session.activateSession()
        }

        getDataFromPhone()
        loadTableData()
    }



@IBAction func refresh() {
        print("menu tapped", terminator: "")
        getDataFromPhone()
        loadTableData()
    }
```